# Popup up when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a join button with class join-button When I click on the button I want to receive an option to either join as member `type A` or member `type B` and then link to the correct page. Could I please get some help tackling this feature? Should I use ajax?

```
<?php if ( !is_user_logged_in() ): ?>
    <a href="www.domain.com" class="join-button">Join</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

css:

```
.join-button {
   -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #f5840c;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #f5840c;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #f5840c;
    background-color:#f5840c;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #f5840c;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding: 1px 4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #f5840c;
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to have even tried implementing this yourself. Give it a shot, use Google to look up tutorials that may help, and if you're having specific coding problems please feel free to come back and edit your question. In the meantime, however, I'm voting to close this as Not Constructive.

Comment: @Kolink, I'll include what I know about the approach.

Comment: You might want to look into a framework such as [codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) or other PHP frameworks to help you understand how things work.

Comment: @RickCigarette I'll look into that -- I am using this button on WordPress website. It seems like this is what I need http://www.gopiplus.com/work/2012/05/25/wordpress-popup-plugin-anything-popup/#.UTmByhzvvmo

Comment: In that case you could use a plugin [for custom user roles](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) and have the two links point to some registration logic with the role as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

just use jquery UI plugin which you can download from [here](http://jqueryui.com/download/)

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
  </script>
<body>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
</body>
```

for better documentation and demos
visit [this link](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) and search the demos for dialog

Answer (score 0):

user Jquery UI plugin here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prabhu5013/6zT4b/1/#update)

```
    $("button.joinbutton").on("click", function () {


  $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    });
```